# how to show both key and value in dictionary in the format they are in

Tags: python

I have a dictionary look like this

`mydict = { 'type' : 'fruit', 'quantity': 20 }`

i wan to print only the 'type' field in the way it is ,like this {'type': 'fruit'}

i found this on other website

```
class fruits(dict):
    def __str__(self):
        return json.dumps(self)
collect = [['apple','grapes']]
result = fruits(collect)
print(result)
```

is there a simpler way without jsonify it?
i also tried .items() method but it print out as (key, value) which i dont wan it to be

Comment: your `fruits` class isn't doing anything useful. `json.dumps` isn't really doing anything different (aside from always emitting valid JSON). You just happened to create a dict with only a single key-value pair. This is pretty much the same as just doing `mydict = {'apple': 'grapes'}; print(mydict)`. your question isn't very clear. if you just want to print a dictionary with *only* the type key, maybe `print({"type": mydict["type"]})`?

Comment: i mean i wan my output to look like {'key' : 'value'}. Above code was from other website that can show the result that i am looking for ,but i believe there is a simpler way to it. And this print({"type": mydict["type"]}) this i am looking for. THANK YOU SIR!

Comment: I am probably missing something obvious, but the code doesn't seem to me to do anything like what you describe to want to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to define a class that behaves exactly like `dict` with the only exception being that it always prints in a particular way, this might be the way to go:

```
class subclass_of_dict(dict):
    def __str__(self):
        return "{'type' : " + f"'{self.get('type')}'" + '}'
```

With your class defined like this, you can now create a couple of instances of this new class:

```
f1 = subclass_of_dict({'type' : 'fruit', 'quantity': 20})
f2 = subclass_of_dict({'type' : 'bowler hats', 'quantity': 13})
```

Then calling `print` on these instances does this:

```
print (f1)
print (f2)

# result: 
    # {'type' : 'fruit'}
    # {'type' : 'bowler hats'}
```

Is this what you're after?